# Animating object transforms with python in 2.81

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I'm building complete Blender 2.81 scenes from scratch in python. I'm pretty expert in python and 3d APIs in general, but new at the Blender python API. I'm stuck on setting up animations (simple TRS for now). 
It seems there are two ways to do it: using Actions, or `keyframe_insert`. I thought the right way in newer Blender is to use actions:

```
  obj.animation_data_create()
  obj.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(name=f'{obj.name}.{path} animation')
  ...
  for i in range(nchannels):
    fcurve = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path=path, index=i)
      ...
      val = kf.value
      blender_kf = fcurve.keyframe_points.insert(frame=kf.time * fps, value=val)
      blender_kf.interpolation = 'LINEAR' # (or something else later)
```

but when I do this, my rotation animation overwrites my earlier translation animation -- I'm not sure what `animation_data` and `action` and `fcurve` actually contain and how many there are of each. I expect I'm overwriting something.

I've heard (?) that as of 2.8 the simpler approach below doesn't work, though I haven't tried it yet:

```
obj.location = (3.0, 4.0, 10.0)
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1)
... and so on for `euler_rotation` and `scale`
```

and also with that method I'm not sure how to set bezier interpolation parameters on the keyframes.

Comment: An action can have fcurves with any datapath.  Example above creates a new action for each `path`   Unless you are dropping then to NLA for example, only the last created action counts.  Using `ob.keyframe_insert` (_which still works in 2.82 btw, can't see them dropping it really_) creates a new action if need be, a new fcurve if need be, and inserts a keyframe(s) at given frame.

Comment: Thanks -- if you make that an answer I can select it as correct. Also, how would I set the interpolation params using `keyframe_insert`? It seems from the API doc that `keyframe_insert` just returns a boolean, not the new keyframe(s).